# how to let dbeaver to highlight sql error for easier development process

Tags: dbeaver

I had a sql that had some error. Although the error says

```
SQL Error [42601]: ERROR: syntax error at or near "from"
  Position: 420
```

. However, it seems dbeaver didn't highlight exactly where the error is. It tells me it is position 420, but i don't know where is position 420 intuitively....

Is it possible to let DBeaver to highlight error for me.

PS: I could identify the error by eyeballing this time... but other times seem difficult...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

DBeaver puts the cursor to the place of error in your query in SQL Editor. For different types of databases. For example, for PostgreSQL, whose error message you, apparently, used in your topic.